# Converting Emgu.CV frame to Bitmap in C#

Tags: c#

I am working with Emgu.CV in my C# project and I'm having trouble converting a frame obtained from a VideoCapture to a Bitmap. I have tried various approaches, but I keep getting errors or the conversion doesn't seem to work correctly.

Here is the relevant part of my code

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;

// ...

VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture("video.mp4");
Mat frame = new Mat();

// Read the frame
if (videoCapture.Read(frame))
{
    // Convert the frame to Bitmap
    Bitmap bitmapFrame = frame.ToBitmap();
    // ...
}
```

When I try to convert the frame to a Bitmap using the ToBitmap() method, I receive an error stating that there is no such method available. I have also tried using frame.Bitmap, but that property doesn't exist either.

Could someone please guide me on how to properly convert an Emgu.CV frame to a Bitmap object in C#?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Emgu.CV.Bitmap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV.Bitmap) is a separate package, you will have to reference it either from NuGet or manually, make sure that the version is the same as that of the installed Emgu.CV. Also `System.Drawing.Common` might be needed depending on which .NET you are working in.